# Unable to use Array.IndexOf in PropertyInfo

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use PropertyInfo as below, but I'm unable to find my property index position using Array.IndexOf method.. Getting -1 only while trying to find the index. Can someone please check and help?

```
public class MyClass {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
}


public class test {

    public void test() {
        PropertyInfo[] propInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties();
        MyClass objMC = new MyClass();

        if (propInfo[Array.IndexOf(propInfo, "name")].GetValue(objMC).ToString().Trim().Equals("zeal")) {
            //matched
        } else {
            // not matched
        }

    }
}
```

But when I try to run the following line, it returns true... So bit confused why I'm unable to use Array.IndexOf here...

> propInfo[0].Name.Equals("name")

Comment: Of course you're getting -1. PropertyInfo is a complex object, and you're trying to compare it to a string ("name"). You should use LINQ's `FirstOrDefault` or similar. For example `propInfo[0] == "name"` would return false, right? They're not the same type.

Comment: @john: Yep I have tried LINQ SingleOrDefault, but got some compilation error like **expression cannot contain lambda expressions**

Comment: Perhaps you could show that code?

Comment: I was trying in a bit different way and that's why got that error... Now I fixed it with @CodingYoshi's example..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use it like shown below because `Array.IndexOf` takes an array and looks for an occurence within the array. Your array has many `PropertyInfo` objects within them and none of them equal the `string` which is `name` so you will get -1 as the result. However, if you select only the names of the `PropertyInfo` objects, then one of them will equal `name`:

```
Array.IndexOf(propInfo.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray() , "name")//...
```